# [Teams][botbuilder] Configuration tab is showing description.full and websiteUrl in the header

Tags: botframework

When app is added to a team, bot is loading configuration tab loaded by "configurableTabs.configurationUrl" url in manifest. It is correct.

But it also displaying large text from "description.full" property above my tab iframe.
How to disable it ?

Comment: can you elaborate more on what you are trying to do? is your issue resolved?

Comment: It is not resolved.. Can you help me with it ? I am trying to get rid of long description text on the configuration tab window. From documentation - we should not see anything above iframe (number 3) but i see long text from my manifest (value from description.full) there -- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/design/tabs#anatomy-tab-configuration-modal